# Validating user token from backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to verify on my backend side (node.js) user's token. Based on the official documentation [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-using-id-and-access-tokens-in-web-api) I should download first all JWT from

`https://cognito-idp.${region}.amazonaws.com/${UserPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json`

But for some reason this address doesn't exists (of course with valid region and UserPoolId). Everything should be configured well because signup, it's confirmation and login works perfectly, users are added to the pool, I've got token. Any idea what can be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

For me the following works to access the JWK Set (basically replaced the region and user pool id in the url above).

https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_O2vEE1sUF/.well-known/jwks.json

https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_O2vEE1sUF/ should be coming from your iss field.

Comment: This is so embarassing, You made me sure that there is nothing obvious which I missed so I checked all again and find out that my region is: "us-west-21" and my UserPoolId starts from "us-west-2_...". So the region number is 2 not 21. Somehow I added it, It works. Thanks for reply.